# Gui crashes after login code

Tags: java, authentication, netbeans-7

This is my Login Code. My code runs fine until it gets to the part where it needs to switch screens to my Homepage. after displaying a "You have logged in!" message it ends the program. any ideas? I am using NetBeans 7.3.1

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    boolean valid = false;

    String user = txtUser.getText();

    String pass = txtPass.getText();



    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));

        while(sc.hasNextLine()){

            String[] line = sc.nextLine().split("#");                

            if(line[0].equals(user) && line[1].equals(pass)){

                valid = true;

            }

        }        

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {}



    if(valid == true){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are now logged in!");
        System.out.println("You are a user!");
        //Doesn't run
        HomePage adm = new HomePage();
        adm.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();

    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your username or password is incorrect!");
    }
```

Comment: Please post your entire error/exception and the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Check what you are exactly disposing in **this.dispose()**. You are possibly disposing JFrame or other component that contains rest of your UI components